# How to construct a Spring Data JPA query method name that compares dates in the entity?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an entity with 2 `java.util.Date` properties, like this (some annotations and details omitted for brevity):

```java
public class Artifact {
    @Column(name = "modified")
    private Date modified;

    @Column(name = "last_deployed")
    private Date lastDeployed;
}
```

In the repository (which extends `JpaRepository<>`) I need a query method that returns all instances of `Artifact` where `lastDeployed` is either `null` or is before the `modified` date. Based on the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.predicate), this method name seems like it should work:

```java
    Stream<Artifact> findByLastDeployedIsNullOrModifiedIsAfterLastDeployed();
```

However, that results in the following error when Spring Date starts up and tries to generate the repository proxy:

```
 org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property isAfterLastDeployed found for type Date! Traversed path: Artifact.modified.
```

I've also tried variations of the query method name that use `IsGreaterThan`, `IsBefore`, etc., but all produce a similar error, where Spring Data seems to think that the query keyword is part of the property name.

How can I construct a query method name that compares two dates in the entity like I need?

Comment: AFAIK you can't compare two columns of the entity using query methods, in such cases use `@Query` instead.

Comment: @birca123 Yes I've worked around it for now with a JPQL query. I was hoping for a query method solution; I'll leave the question open in case someone else has an answer.